# How to bind input value using ngFor and ngModel?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have `ngFor` on input that will have mulitple inputs now i want to bind those inpt values to component so that can be used in the logic once input values added, issue is its not showing input fields so i can push the data to `subQuestionsAnswertext`.

app.component.html

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="showSubQuestionsQues"> 
                                  <div  *ngFor="let option of singleQuestion.answerOption">
                                    <div *ngFor="let sub of option.subQuestion">
                                        <div *ngFor="let ques of sub.question">
                                            <label for="subQuestionsInput">{{ques.questionText}}</label>
                                            <input type="subQuestionsInput" class="form-control" *ngIf="((ques.responseFieldIdentifier == DOES LEFT) || (ques.responseFieldIdentifier == NEXT DOSE))" placeholder="quantity" [(ngModel)]="ques.answerText">                                            </div> 
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import {
    Component,
    OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
    ApiService
} from './api.service';
import {
    EventService
} from './format-questions/format-questions.service'
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent Implement OnInit {
    subQuestionsAnswertext: any = [];
    constructor(private dataService: ApiService, private eventService: EventService) {}
    ngOnInit(e) {
        this.subQuestionsAnswertext.push(e.answerText);
    }
}
```

Comment: have try setting index and using in ngModel because when you use ngFor then mode name has to different. Give fiddle

Comment: so the inputs are not showing? Well, seems for example this is an issue: `(ques.responseFieldIdentifier == NEXT DOSE)` Are you trying to match a string, like `(ques.responseFieldIdentifier == "NEXT DOSE")`?

Comment: @AJT82 input bind only last value that is entered in the second input i want to capture both input values

Answer (score 0):

Can you please replace Input field HTML -

Reason - currently `NEXT DOSE` is treated as a variable. you need to change this to a string.

```html
<input type="texy" class="form-control" *ngIf="((ques.responseFieldIdentifier == 'DOES LEFT') || (ques.responseFieldIdentifier == 'NEXT DOSE'))" placeholder="quantity" [(ngModel)]="ques.answerText">
```